# Ended Events in Community Bulletin Don't Go Away

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-bulletin, events

I happened to have a question open at the point where a chat event in the community bulletin ended. The time indicator on the event kept on ticking, showing me how long it had been since the "upcoming event" had ended.

[image]

Would it make more sense for these to vanish from the sidebar when they were done?

Comment: Ends 13 mins ago? I'm seeing this bug in TeX last month.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: you have a cache that auto-updates itself every minute? :)

Comment: What you see there is a timestamped div that a *client side* javascript routine converts to relative time - the routine runs in intervals.

Comment: @Oded still, some sanity check is expected. In the very least, show just "ended" and not a broken and incorrect message.